# Isolated DC supply for Bluetooth receiver in car audio

Tags: voltage-regulator, noise

This question is about the isolated power supply I've put together for a Bluetooth receiver which is going into an old car stereo, replacing the cassette...

The Bluetooth device wants isolated 5vdc, and the supply is of course the 12-13.5vdc from the car.

I have made a regulator unit, which works, but it was just based on info I gleaned from datasheets etc. (The B0505S-1W being the DC-DC isolator.)

This is the circuit...

[image: isolated 5vdc power supply]

It works fine on the bench (haven't yet tested it in the car), the Bluetooth unit is well within the power draw specs of the B0505W and the 7805 has a heatsink on it because it was getting hot.

The question is - are these the right cap choices, and, should it have an inductor to further help filter it seeing as it's in a car?

Thanks for looking at this.

[New question to add to this]
I have made some additions to this power supply circuit for protection namely a TVS Diode 16v.

New question: I keep seeing recommendations to add a resistor before the TVS diode, and one after - but I can't find information about what size resistors to use. It's car voltage coming in - eg ~13.5v - and the load is under 1W.

Comment: Why does the bluetooth want isolated 5V? Besides, you’ll need a bit more protection for the 7805. Automotive is a harsh environment.

Comment: What sort of protection should the 7805 have? Could you recommend anything? And re the isolator: a few people doing these conversions online complain of ground loop or other noise and some Bluetooth receivers come with B0505S isolators on the board. So - preemptively I put it in.

Comment: Use a 12 to 5V dc/dc converter then. Get rid of the 7805.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion Kartman. I did think about that - but the B1205S has (according to datasheet) an input range of 10.8-13.2v and the 7805 has an input range of 7v-24v - which I thought would be better in a car with it's variable voltage going over 13v. But either way - what protection would you suggest before either of these - bigger cap? Inductor?

Comment: Overvoltage and transient protection. An inductor would only be for EMC. Choose a dc/dc converter with better input range.

Comment: The power going to this voltage regulator/isolator and its Bluetooth receiver comes from within the car stereo, with whatever power regulation it has - in fact it's the 12v pin that used to go to the cassette player motor. a quick glance includes

Comment: Well, its a case of suck it and see. If it works and keeps on working - then good. If you were making 1000’s of them, you’d want to be more diligent. For a one off, car stereos vary, so it is a bit of a guessing game. When it works, it is the sweet taste of success!

Comment: Whoops we're been warned not to make this discussion too long... - so just to conclude - thanks Kartman. I will check out a better 12v-5v isolator, and a 15v TVS diode. I'll find out when it's back in the car how much the voltage is stable within the stereo.